# Is there a difference between the legal meaning of the term "ordonnance" and "statutory instrument"?

Tags: legal-terms

We have currently a debate at the Wikidata [Project Chat](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:Project_chat#Merging_problem) about whether the term [ordonnance](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q2703920) (the idea that it's equivalent to the German word Verordnung) and the term [statutory instrument](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q3704604) have the same legal meaning.

Is the meaning the same? Is one a subclass of the other?

Comment: Whatever conclusion you come to, *ordinance* would be more recognized, unless you are referring specifically to French law; see [this definition](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/ordonnance).

Comment: Neither term, spelled like those terms are, have a well defined meaning in American law.

Answer (score 1):

In UK law, a "statutory instrument" is a particular class of legislation defined in section 1 of the Statutory Instruments Act 1946. This envisages broadly three forms: Orders in Council made by the Crown; rules made by ministers where the power conferred is exercisable by "statutory instrument"; similarly for Welsh ministers.

In other words, most statutory instruments are statutory instruments because the legislation conferring powers on a minister to make them say that they are. There's no default. It is possible to confer powers on a minister which are exercisable without being an SI (though I cannot think of any examples of this).

I believe that there are some statutory powers to make SI's conferred outside the 1946 Act to parts of local government.

As I understand it, an Ordonnance (a French word) refers to a form of French legislation of a specific kind, whereas almost anything could be done by SI. Some SI's might amend Acts of Parliament; others might directly implement EU legislation; others might simply set speed limits or tolls on the Humber Bridge.

The point here is that SI's are a means of numbering and indexing legislation. That is all. An SI is not a particular class of rule having a particular status. The consequences of being an SI are essentially being given a number.

So I think it would be confusing to conflate the two ideas.